# how to include css in node_modules folder from Django project?

Tags: django, npm, webpack

We started using npm to install javascript libraries.

We didn't have to collectstatic the javascript files under `node_modules` directory since webpack includes them during bundling process.

How do we include css / less / sass files under `node_modules` from our html or javascript files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe too late to the party, but I put here my solution if anybody still needs it.

**notes**:

- In the example below I use Bootstrap as reference but the same approach works with all npm dependencies:
- I use `django-sass-processor` to manage scss in Django but you can handle scss as you want in your project

**package.json**

```json
...
"devDependencies": {
  "bootstrap": "5.1.3"
}
...
```

After running `npm i` command you will get a tree similar to the following:

```sh
.
├── ...
├── your-django-app
│   ├── static
│   │   ├── ...
│   │   └── styles
│   │       ├── custom.scss
│   │       └── ...
│   └── ...
├── manage.py
├── node_modules
│   └── bootstrap
│       ├── ...
│       └── scss
│           ├── _accordion.scss
│           ├── _alert.scss
│           ├── _badge.scss
│           └── ...
├── ...
```

in `custom.scss` you can then import specific SCSS from the node_modules dependency, like:

**custom.scss**

```
@import "../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/accordion";
@import "../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/alert";
@import "../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/badge";
```

In your template you can then reference `custom.scss` like:

```html
{% load static %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% sass_src 'styles/custom.scss' %}">
```

In this way you can selectively import the needed css from **node_modules**  into your project.

Answer (score 1):

Same way webpack collects files for you from `node_modules`, same way Django collects them from `STATICFILES_DIRS`.

So, add a directory into `STATICFILES_DIRS` list and there you go.

Comment: We didn't include node_modules as staticfiles_dirs as I commented in OP. Because for javascript, we didn't have to.

Comment: Well for Django you have to indicate folders where to get the static files from.